# How to play an attack animation plus adding a certain amount of damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to put one attack animation working and it is playing non-stop instead of playing when I press left-shift.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For now, that is what I have.

Comment: I guess its something with the states in your animator. Are you sure that the transitions between the 2 states are correct?

Answer (score 2):

Set a null state or an idle in your controller and make sure it's the base state, create a parameter trigger name Attack, drag your animation into the controller and transition from base to your attack anim with the parameter as attack and a transition back.

In code on shift press write
anim.setTrigger ("Attack");

Also if u haven't referenced your animation by either draging it in to your variable or a getcomonent ref it also wont work :)